# How to use python coverage inside the code

Tags: python, code-coverage

I want to capture the coverage from inside the code. I tried below one but getting error. Referred to below link for coverage API.
https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/api.html#api

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
import coverage

cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

#actual code

cov.stop()
cov.save()

cov.html_report(directory='covhtml')
```

getting below errors

```
CoverageException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2047badbbd57> in <module>()
     48 cov.save()
     49 
---> 50 cov.html_report(directory='covhtml')

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.pyc in html_report(self, morfs, directory, ignore_errors, omit, include, extra_css, title, skip_covered)
   1093             )
   1094         reporter = HtmlReporter(self, self.config)
-> 1095         return reporter.report(morfs)
   1096 
   1097     def xml_report(

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\coverage\html.pyc in report(self, morfs)
    137 
    138         # Process all the files.
--> 139         self.report_files(self.html_file, morfs, self.config.html_dir)
    140 
    141         if not self.all_files_nums:

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\coverage\report.pyc in report_files(self, report_fn, morfs, directory)
     81 
     82         if not file_reporters:
---> 83             raise CoverageException("No data to report.")
     84 
     85         self.directory = directory

CoverageException: No data to report.
```

Comment: Can you say why you want to use the coverage API? Why not just run coverage on the command line?

Comment: I am having a shell script which is calling different python scripts. So, I feel for each python script I can insert the coverage code and redirect the output to a separate directory for each python script. This looks cleaner than command line option.

Comment: I don't know why that seems cleaner to you.  Coverage measurement should be an optional process that you can apply to existing code.  You can change one line in a shell script to make it happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrap whatever you have for `#actual code` in a function, then it will work. Here's a (minimalish) example:

```
import coverage

def test_it(x):
    return x + 1

cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

test_it(123)

cov.stop()
cov.save()

cov.html_report(directory='covhtml')
```

However, if you would replace `test_it(123)` by just doing some inline statement (like `x = 123; x += 1; print(x)`), then the coverage module will fail.

It's well hidden, but the docs do explain this behavior:

> start()
>
> Start measuring code coverage.
>
> **Coverage measurement only occurs in functions called after start() is
>   invoked. Statements in the same scope as start() won’t be measured.**
>
> Once you invoke start(), you must also call stop() eventually, or your
>   process might not shut down cleanly.

Emphasis my own, here's the link: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/api_coverage.html#coverage.Coverage.start

Comment: Matt - I tried your code but its failing too with same error.

Comment: @RishiBansal You're sure? You copy/pasted it *exactly* as-is into a new file, and ran that file through your python interpreter? It works for me (just double check with a quick copy/paste), I'm on Python 3.6, MacOS.

Comment: Yeah, I tried again and its failing. I am using Python 2.7 Anaconda/Jupiter, Windows 10.

Comment: @RishiBansal What version of coverage do you have? I just tried with Python 2.7 from a conda env, it still worked. The version I have is 4.5.1. To get the version, do `import coverage; coverage.__version__`.

Comment: @RishiBansal To be safe, I think it also works best if your code to be covered is in a different module as well. That also might fix the issue.

Comment: Your code is working on a linux server but I don't have certain libraries on that prod server so I need to run it on my windows machine. Still trying.

Comment: @RishiBansal This likely has nothing to do with linux vs windows. Try running it as a standalone script, *not* in a Jupyter notebook.